# Activity not finish when press back button

Tags: android, android-activity

My activity has a strange behavior. I've override onBackPressed() method for perform some task before close activity, but i need to press twice back button for exit. What's wrong?

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    String[] children = temp_directory.list();
    for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
        new File(temp_directory, children[i]).delete();
    }
    finish();
}
```

EDIT:
i've noticed that when i press back button for first time, OnResume method is called.

EDIT TWO: 
if i remove all cleanup on files, and write :

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    finish();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.i("TAG", "ondestroy");
}
```

at first back pressed, onresume is called. On second tap, ondestroy is called, but twice (log print message twice only after second back tap)

Comment: Why not put your cleanup code in `onDestory` method?

Comment: What class you activity is inherited from? Is it plain android Activity or some custom class?

Comment: I need to exit only from current activity, and my activity it's a plain android activity

Comment: try dropping the `super.onBackPressed()` call altogether to see if that solves anything.

Comment: target is 18, and min is 11

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier i've removed also cleanup code, but the situation is the same. I need to push back twice for get the previous FragmentActivity

Comment: we can conclude that the cleanup code is not the problem. That is good to know.

Comment: you may have multiple activities without knowing it. Try changing log line to `Log.i("TAG", "ondestroy " + this);` and see if the value changes

Answer (score 1):

---

### Attempt 2

I wrote some experimental code below that tries to duplicate the problem of taking too long to delete the files. What I found is that the activity exits right away, without delaying for the 10 seconds.

This proves that the call to `super.onBackPressed()` would normally exit your activity - the code doesn't get to deleting the files.

```
public void onBackPressed()
{
    // this call would exit the activity
    super.onBackPressed();

    // long delay - pretending to delete files - never runs
    try
    {
        Thread.sleep(10000);
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e)
    {
    }

    finish();
}
```

**Update:** @nickes points out that this is only true for the root activity. A second activity launched WILL experience the delay.

This different behaviour depending on how many activities are on the stack can be seen in the code for `Activity.finish()` [on grepcode here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2.2_r1/android/app/Activity.java#Activity.finish%28%29):

```
public void finish() {
    if (mParent == null) {
        int resultCode;
        Intent resultData;
        synchronized (this) {
            resultCode = mResultCode;
            resultData = mResultData;
        }
        if (Config.LOGV) Log.v(TAG, "Finishing self: token=" + mToken);
        try {
            if (ActivityManagerNative.getDefault()
                .finishActivity(mToken, resultCode, resultData)) {
                mFinished = true;
            }
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            // Empty
        }
    } else {
        mParent.finishFromChild(this);
    }
}
```

**Update 2:** @giozh removed all cleanup code, and still has the problem. So the clean-up code / delay is not the issue.

---

### Attempt 1

Try removing `finish()` and move `super.onBackPressed()` to the end:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    String[] children = temp_directory.list();
    for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
        new File(temp_directory, children[i]).delete();
    }

    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Based on @nickes comment above, made me think it could be the superclass that prevents the activity from closing - so another option would just be to remove the call to `super.onBackPressed()`.

**Update:** @giozh confirms that the superclass is a plain old vanilla `Activity`, so this is not the solution.

Comment: I wrote my own experimental code and have found that Thread.sleep(10000) won't affect response time only if it is a root activity. If it is second (for example) activity on back stack then Thread.sleep(10000) would stall application. It looks like if you exiting root activity applicaton woldn't stall just because Android kills app process.

Comment: Yes, this is starting to look like a lot of fun =)

Comment: Plus, just copied your idea - I see also that the `super.onBackPressed()` is NOT closing the 2nd activity. So the cleanup code DOES run - hence the delay.

Comment: @nickes the source code (reference above) shows these 2 different ways that `finish()` works. Thanks for highlighting that for me.

Answer (score 1):

It is because your cleanup takes too much time. You think that first back press doesn't work and press again. Try to do you cleanup async. And of course `onDestroy()` is a lot more better place to do this.

Or you Activity is inherited from some class that overrides `onBackPressed()`

Comment: the cleanup code would not be run under normal circumstances - see my edit - strange

Comment: i've put cleanup inside onDestroy(), but result is the same.